# Check if multiple $_SESSION vars are empty

Tags: php, session

Basically people have a choice what kind of activity they want to do. This is being done with checkboxes. My old code was kinda trash to i decided to clean it up a bit. So, the checked POST variables are being put in a SESSION like this;

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    for($x = 0; $x < $keuzelength; $x++) {
    $_SESSION[$keuze[$x]] = $_POST[$keuze[$x]];
    }
    }
```

This works like a charm but, after this i want to check if they are ALL empty. Only if they are all empty the error needs to popup. Currently thats done like this:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['Dierentuin']) && 
    empty($_SESSION['Bowlen']) && 
    empty($_SESSION['Attractiepark']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Wandelen']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Hardlopen']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Uitgaan']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Zwemmen']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Karten']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Lasergamen']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Paintballen']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Klimmen']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Museum']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Kanovaren']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Weekend weg']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Verras me']) &&
    empty($_SESSION['Poolen'])){

    print('error text');
                exit();
                }
```

This basically checks if any of the above are empty the script stopts and sends an error. Works like a charm. But, as soon as i add a new choice to the array which is used for the checkboxes i need to add another empty line in there.

Is there a way to check all $_SESSION[$keuze[]] variables?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just do it inside the loop that you are using to assign the POST values to the session ... initialize a flag `$has_errors=false` before the loop, and inside check if the current item is empty - if so, set flag to true. And then after the loop, act accordingly based on whether the flag is true or false.

Comment: @C0dekid : still, he'll have to add a line anytime he adds a choice :/

Comment: put the session keys inside a separate array `$_SESSION['test']['Dierentuin']` and use `array_filter($_SESSION['test'])` on that array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Doesn't work, because i also store other things in session variables.

As suggested by @ImClarky, create another array to store all the values you want to check,  i.e.:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    for($x = 0; $x < $keuzelength; $x++) {
    $_SESSION['custom_sessions'][$keuze[$x]] = $_POST[$keuze[$x]];
    }
 }
```

Then you can use `array_filter` to check is `$_SESSION['custom_sessions']` is empty, i.e.:

```
if (!array_filter($_SESSION['custom_sessions']))
{
    print('error text'); # empty array
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work, because i also store other things in session variables.

Comment: @MilkTea - Perhaps if you had something like `$_SESSION['keuze'][$keuze[$x]]` in your loop, you could then `array_filter($_SESSION['keuze'])`

Comment: Nice suggestion @ImClarky, I've updated my answer, tks!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks alot!

Comment: @PedroLobito I have another question you might know, i use a select statement after, where it should get all the inserted checkbox's. The ones inside the `$_SESSION['custom_sessions']` but somehow i cant get it to work. i already found this `$sql = 'SELECT * 
          FROM 'table' 
         WHERE 'id' IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $array)) . ')';` but that just leaves my page empty. when i change $array to the $_SESSION